# Floating AutoComplete in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-paper

I am looking for an autocomplete-text-input with the floating suggestion box.

Please suggest me any package name that can help to make the same component.

I tried to many packages but nothing helps, some are pushing the next fields, others do not support click away listener.

[image: Autocomplete text input sample]

Comment: Have you tried [react-native-autocomplete-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input)

Comment: Yes, I did but it is not floating over below fields, I tried work around it and give position absolute to get it at a specific position. But it is not recommendable from my side, Still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer: I Suggest One Solution:

#### Step 1:

```
npm install react-native-autocomplete-input --save
```

#### Step 2:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

// Import all the components we are going to use
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

// Import Autocomplete component
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

const App = () => {
  // For Main Data
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
  // For Filtered Data
  const [filteredFilms, setFilteredFilms] = useState([]);
  // For Selected Data
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/getpost.php?offset=1')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const {results: films} = json;
        setFilms(films);
        //setting the data in the films state
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert(e);
      });
  }, []);

  const findFilm = (query) => {
    // Method called every time when we change the value of the input
    if (query) {
      // Making a case insensitive regular expression
      const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
      // Setting the filtered film array according the query
      setFilteredFilms(
          films.filter((film) => film.title.search(regex) >= 0)
      );
    } else {
      // If the query is null then return blank
      setFilteredFilms([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          // Data to show in suggestion
          data={filteredFilms}
          // Default value if you want to set something in input
          defaultValue={
            JSON.stringify(selectedValue) === '{}' ?
            '' :
            selectedValue.title
          }
          // Onchange of the text changing the state of the query
          // Which will trigger the findFilm method
          // To show the suggestions
          onChangeText={(text) => findFilm(text)}
          placeholder="Enter the film title"
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            // For the suggestion view
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                setSelectedValue(item);
                setFilteredFilms([]);
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                  {item.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          {films.length > 0 ? (
            <>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                   Selected Data
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                {JSON.stringify(selectedValue)}
              </Text>
            </>
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>
                Enter The Film Title
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  autocompleteContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderWidth: 0,
  },
  descriptionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    margin: 2,
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
export default App;
```

Comment: That's Pretty and Easy Solution thank you Jahnavi!!!

Comment: Your Welcome Yash!

Comment: Hi @JahnaviSananse, I'm facing a similar issue I've tried so many things. Here is my issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77147563/react-native-autocompleteinput-suggestionlist-opens-in-different-item . Could you please help me with this?