# React native AutoCompleteInput suggestionlist opens in different item

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, dropdown

I'm using AutocompleteInput from 'react-native-autocomplete-input'.I've multiple items and I'm presenting those items in card view. No in that card view, I need some TextInputs and autocomplete. Now my main problem is if I search in 1st item autocomplete suggestionlist will open in the last item.

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the list maybe? There is an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

The basic idea is just calling reverse on your array before passing it as the data prop in the autocomplete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).